# Ubuntu 18.04 no display on ASUS ROG (GL703VD-GC083T)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm currently running a semi-broken Ubuntu 17 installation on the ASUS ROG-GL703VD.

Hoping that some of my issues (wifi sometimes not working on boot, random fan speedups, **no touchpad**) will be solved using a newer Ubuntu version, I tried to update to Ubuntu 18.

After upgrading I noticed that my laptop display turns off during boot, at first I thought this was an issue related to upgrading rather than a fresh install, but running the Ubuntu 18.04 liveUSB also turns off the display once selected "Try Ubuntu without installing".

In order to install Ubuntu 16.04 (from which I upgraded to 17.10) I had to set `nouveau_modeset=0` in order to boot with display, Now I tried doing the very same with as well `modeset=0, nouveau_modeset=0, nomodeset` but neither of those will allow me to boot with a display.

I tried running the installer with a external display attached as well but that also didn't resolve the problem for me.

Is there a way to debug why my display turns off as soon as Ubuntu launches the x-server?

Comment: Two numbers aren't enough to specify Ubuntu versions.  We can infer (for now) that your reference to 18 to mean 18.04 because 18.10 hasn't been released yet.  A person reading this thread might not be sure 8 months from now.  As far as your versions 16 and 17 references, we can't tell.  It would help if you would edit your question and specify real Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I didn't specify a second number because for me it doesn't make a difference, I tried the daily build of 18.10 as well as I did with 18.04, with both I experienced the same issue. I will update the initial question nevertheless

Comment: It makes a big difference.  Version 18.10 isn't supported on this site.  It would be off topic.  We would point you to the best help based on what you are using.  Thanks for clarifying so that we could provide the best help.  By the way, welcome to AU!  Hope you get the best support.  It's still not clear to me which version you are currently running.  What works with version 18.04 LTS may not work with version 18.10.

Comment: Your problem appears to be arrising from version conflicts.  You should pick a specific version and try to get that one working.  If you get a specific version working and decide to change, there's a good chance you might be able to apply the same fix to the next version you install.  You named 4 versions in your question.  Each of the 4 versions has very significant changes.  More changes that Ubuntu has had in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tested it on 18.04 mainly, I just pointed out 18.10 because the issue still persists in that release after trying that. As pointed out, 17.10 seems to be working after an upgrade, however I'm not sure if I'm able to boot into a 17.10 installer because I haven't tried that yet. Nevertheless, upgrading or attempting a fresh install of 18.04(/18.10) isn't working and I lack the possibility to analyze log files to see what is going on. for now, let's stick to 18.04 as distribution i'm trying to get installed :)

Comment: I wouldn't try an upgrade to 18.10 on a machine that I wasn't running just for testing and developing.  This would introduce a lot of problems, and a lot of time to address the issues.  The issues with 18.10 would have to be addressed with the development team.  It will be months before 18.10 would have stability.  If you have 18.10 on your machine, many things that I could suggest you try would probably not work because of the differences that is being tested and considered for implementing into the new version.  I usually test resolutions that I provide.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to immediatly test 18.10 because I wouldn't currently have the time.  If I did start to test it, I would do it on a site where the topic would be available for discussion.  If I knew you were having problems with a specific supported version, I would test any resolution that I provide on the actual version to try to minimze giving something that might fail.  I can't over emphasize the huge difference between what is under the hood of 16.04 and 18.04.  Some of the things are very sudtle.  Some are intended, some or not.  But there are lots of difference.

Comment: I believe you without doubt on changes underneath the hood, unfortunately I can't tell you anything other than that my laptop works/boots on ubuntu 17.10, and it doesn't (atleast not the display) on Ubuntu 18.*, if you can provide me a method to gather some logs or whatsoever I'd be happy to supply them to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79034/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-grx).

Answer (score 0):

Please boot the server version of 18.04 and then check `~/x-session.errors`, `/var/log/Xorg*` and `/var/log/syslog` on your original install for messages related to Nouveau, NVidia and related.

Comment: Sadly, I'm unable to analyze them, as I only have the option from the liveUSB installer to boot into a x-server mode (instead of CLI), and from that point on, I can't even reach other TTY's in order to check these logs since the display is turned off.

Comment: @GRX See update to answer